# how to sort php category arrays alphabetically?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following piece of code that returns a number of categories, along with a counter of items in each category. The problem is that it's not returned alphabetically. How can I force them to be output alphabetically? I think it has to be with "asort" or something but I can't seem to figure out how. I'd greatly appreciate any advice! :)

The array to be alphabetically sorted is:

```
 $category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']]
```

The complete code:

```
 while ($cat_details = $db->fetch_array($sql_select_categories))
 {
  $subcat_link = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '?parent_id=' .$cat_details['category_id'] . $additional_vars;

  $categoryCounter = (COUNT_CATS == 1 && !empty($src_details['keywords_search'])) ? $cat_counter[$cat_details['category_id']] : $cat_details['items_counter'];

  if ($categoryCounter > 0 || COUNT_CATS == 0) {
  $output .= '<tr> ' .
        '   <td class="contentfont"><a href="' . $subcat_link . '">' . $category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']] . '</a> ' .
        (($categoryCounter) ? '<span class="cnt">(' . $categoryCounter . ')</span>' : '') .
        '  </td> ' .
        '</tr> ';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array=$category_lang[$cat_details['category_id']]

asort($array);
 //Now $array is sorted alphabetically. use it as you want.
```

You can use foreach loop through array element.

asort, sorts an array maintaining the index of the elements associated.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases it is better to use mysql ORDER BY name ASC